# Warm weather equivalent of "bundle up"

Tags: phrase-request

When it is cold outside, parents inform their children that they should "bundle up" to dress properly for the cold. **What is the warm-weather analogue** to this phrase, that would be used to inform their children that they should dress properly for the heat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could say "**Dress lightly** for the heat."

For example,

> [Heat exhaustion is dangerous and can lead to Heatstroke, a life-threatening condition. It helps to be equipped with knowledge of preventative measures. Here are a few tips that will help you and your loved ones stay safe in the Georgia heat. 
>
>    **Dress Lightly**
>
>   You already know that less is more when it comes to summer attire. Wearing lightweight clothing instead of heavy winter garments is a given. Plus, natural fibers such as cotton, linen and silk, especially in loose-fitting clothes, keep you more comfortable as they allow your skin to breathe, enabling perspiration to evaporate more easily.](https://applecaredoctors.com/blog/how-to-beat-georgias-summer-heat)

Comment: Thank you! I've upvoted but I do not yet have enough reputation for my votes to count.

Answer (score 3):

You could say

> It's going to be hot. Wear [loose, light clothing](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22loose%20light%20clothing%22&t=ha&ia=web) to stay cool | avoid sunstroke.

There's nothing similar to the phrasal "bundle up" except perhaps **strip down** but that phrase is often used with taking everything off or everything but underclothing off, so it might be misunderstood.

> Here’s the thing — dog’s have fur coats. They wear them all the time. They can’t strip down in the heat.

Comment: This is a good answer as well. I've upvoted but do not yet have enough reputation for my votes to count.